# Is There Any Important Difference Between These Two SwiftUI Drag Gesture Implementations?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

## Drag Gesture Implementation

While trying to make a simple drag gesture without the long press I found that two different ways seem to produce the same result. I am unsure if one method is preferable to another or if both are equally valid.

### Example 1

Here I used @State CGSize values to represent both the viewState and the dragState

```swift
struct Example1: View {
    @State var viewState: CGSize = .zero
    @State var dragState: CGSize = .zero

    var body: some View {
        let dragGesture = DragGesture()
            .onChanged { (value) in
                self.dragState = value.translation
        }.onEnded { (value) in
            self.viewState.width += value.translation.width
            self.viewState.height += value.translation.height
            self.dragState = .zero
        }
        return Circle().foregroundColor(.blue).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            .offset(x: dragState.width + viewState.width,
                    y: dragState.height + viewState.height)
            .gesture(dragGesture)

    }
}
```

### Example 2

This time I made the structure similar to the Composing SwiftUI Gestures article but without the long press gesture.

```swift
struct Example2: View {
    @State var viewState: CGSize = .zero
    @GestureState var dragState: DragState = .inactive

    enum DragState {
        case inactive
        case active(translation: CGSize)

        var translation: CGSize {
            switch self {
            case .active(translation: let translation):
                return translation
            default:
                return .zero
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        let dragGesture = DragGesture()
            .updating($dragState) { (value, state, _) in
                state = .active(translation: value.translation)
        }.onEnded { (value) in
            self.viewState.width += value.translation.width
            self.viewState.height += value.translation.height
        }

        return Circle().foregroundColor(.red).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            .offset(x: dragState.translation.width + viewState.width,
                    y: dragState.translation.height + viewState.height)
            .gesture(dragGesture)
    }
}
```

### Main Question

Do either of these implementations do anything under the hood that I'm missing or are they exactly the same?